# IF statement returns TRUE and/or FALSE but not calculation

Tags: excel, if-statement

```
=IF([@[Total 2012]]<>0,([@[Total 2013]]/[@[Total 2012]]*100),100,IF(AND([@[Total 2012]]=0,[@[Total 2013]]=0),0,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're formula does not work - it has one parameter too much:

```
=IF(
1:   [@[Total 2012]]<>0,
2:   ([@[Total 2013]]/[@[Total 2012]]*100),
3:   100,
4:   IF(AND([@[Total 2012]]=0,[@[Total 2013]]=0),0,0)
)
```

`IF` needs only three - *condition*, *result when true*, *result when false*. So need to change it to what you need.

Also note, that your 4th parameter will always return `0`, as the nested `IF` formula there has `0` for both, true and false part.